# Change html text using php

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to use an **apache filter**, that would make some simple manipulation to an html website. To test it, I'm simply not changing the html. I have the following php code:

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin','r');
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout','w');
while ($line = fgets($stdin)){
  fwrite($stdout,$line);
}
fclose($stdin);
fclose($stdout);
?>
```

The filter I'm using is:

```
ExtfilterDefine tester mode=output intype=text/html cmd="tester.php"
SetOutputFilter tester
```

When I add sleep(5) to any part of the php, I can see that the site takes longer to load. However, testing with a simple site with a header and one line, it returns a blank page.
Trying with a more complicated site, it returns a half broken site. 
Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a while statement around your `fgets()`function, since it only catches one line of the current file?

Comment: Thanks, I had that to start with, and then in a failed attempt to simplify it, it went wrong. The original code was:

    while ($line=fgets($stdin)){
      $line = preg_replace('/a/','A',$line);
      fwrite($stdout, $line);
    }

Comment: And that went wrong too?

Comment: Yes, it returns a blank page. I wonder if the input is being read correctly, as adding sleep(5) in the while doesn't put it to sleep. So I guess the input is corrupt/blank?